# Methods to convert appx to xap

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, converters, xap, appx

The title says it all. Is it possible to convert *.appx file to *.xap file? I am limited only to emulators that can handle xap. 
These work in windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. If your emulators can handle only XAP packages, that menas you have Windows Phone 8.0 emulators. APPX packages are for 8.1 apps and you cannot run 8.1 apps in an 8.0 emulator.